# Replace a color with another color in an image with CSS3

Tags: image, css, replace, colors

You can replace one color with another in CSS3?

[image]
[image]

Comment: for what purpose you need this?

Answer (score 3):

by a little tricks you can do this easily . just turn the inside of image ,transparent and then

[image]

```
<style type="text/css">
.bx{
  width: 73px;
  height: 73px;
  background: transparent url("top.png") no-repeat;
}
.bx.yellow{background-color: yellow}
.bx.green{background-color: green}
</style>
```

and

```
<div class="bx"></div>
<div class="bx yellow"></div>
<div class="bx green"></div>
```

at the end
[image]

Comment: Is good but I have a more complex image with more colors to change.

Comment: @AdrianSimionescu for this type of thing usually work just with images, for example. for green and yellow color, just use green and yellow images, and load them by the user operation